# Leveraging H2O to determine what impacts weight gain or loss

Tags: algorithm, factors

I was looking for guidance as to how to solve a particular problem I have. I keep a log of what food I eat on a daily basis and what impact does it have on my weight. The log looks something like this.

```
Date,MorningWeight,YesterdayFactors
2016-06-11,182.6,salad sleep:0.15 cheese egg halfnhalf:1.5
2016-06-12,181.0,sleep:0.5 tea grape
2016-06-13,183.6,bagel bread date:1.5 dietsnapple splenda pizza nosleep:0.2
2016-06-14,183.7,coffeecandy cheese rice salmon peanut bread
2016-06-15,183.4,salmon salad cherry:0.7 dietsnapple tea potato oliveoil cheese peanut
2016-06-16,183.8,bread avocado:10 sugaryogurt dietsnapple peanut ketchup
2016-06-17,182.6,salmon pistachio peanut cheese
2016-06-18,182.4,bread:0 peanut bagel cheese cherry soup
```

I wanted to find out what factors are impacting my weight the most. I wanted some help to see how best to solve this problem using H2O. Specifically, what algorithm would help given that the food intake would vary on a day to day basis.

Comment: Some more detail is required.  What have you tried so far, and how did this fail?

Comment: I am a newbie.  I have looked at various examples that come bundled with H2O to see what would be suitable.  This seems to be a regression based case where perhaps computing the Coefficient Magnitudes would give me the relative importance of each food to the weight gain.  However, I do not know how to go about picking an example that I would start to look at and model based on.  In all the examples, the factors are the the same for each case.  However, in my use case, I might eaten one set of food items one day, but I might not have the same the next.  Thanks and regards.

Comment: I do not think you can do this just from the log like this.... to see the impact you would need to eat some kind of stuff for a longer period .... and then measure ... the result can vary a lot dependent on time when you eat, what you do, environment (especially humidity and temperature) and do not forget that combination of foods is not the same as eating them separately . Eating habits are also a big factor (like are you eating while watching Tv or doing something else?) . And lastly your body propositions and daily routine with your health conditions do a lot too ...

Comment: so in my opinion even if you regress some kind of dependency it would be just numerical coincidence and not a real dependency of weight on food intake.

Comment: To your point Spektre, one could add other factors like exercise, sleep, state of mind, etc. as input along the same lines as food.